# Is is okay to pluralize a type of company I worked for on my resume?

Tags: resume

I have worked at mutliple companies but only one of them is a Cloud 100 company. Is it okay for me to write the following sentence in my resume:

> I have implemented information technology solutions for Cloud 100 companies in the enterprise software and web development sectors.

I don't think I'm outright lying, but I can see how this can be deceptive. Here's an alternative I thought of:

> I have implemented information technology solutions for both Cloud 100 and startup companies in the enterprise software and web development sectors.

It doesn't sound as nice. If you can help me frame this sentence better, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: Your second statement is perfectly fine.

Comment: I slightly prefer it, as it shows versatility and a range of working environments.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I agree that saying "Cloud 100 companies" is deceptive, as it implies multiple Cloud 100 companies. Your second phrasing is not bad, but instead I would say

> I have implemented information technology solutions for multiple companies in the enterprise and web development sectors, including a Cloud 100 company.

Your resume should include the names of the companies you worked for anyway, so it should be pretty clear there's only one Cloud 100 company, but redundancy is not always a bad thing.

Comment: The Cloud 100 list, much like the Fortune 500 list, is a list of the top 100 companies in cloud computing as published by Forbes magazine.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying though. I'll think of a better way to phrase my sentence.

Comment: @AaditMShah Ah, thanks for clarifying. I edited my post to the phrasing I think makes the most sense.

Answer (score 3):

First one is a lie.

Second one does not scan too well

How about

> I have implemented IT solutions for the enterprise and web development
>   sectors(one company being a cloud 100 company).

Comment: Thank you. I'll find a better way to phrase this sentence.

Comment: "companies ranging in size from startup to Cloud 100" for example?